# Private key parameters in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, private-key

I got an application that in C#, using RSACryptoServiceProvider, I load a public key from an XML and then I'm encrypting a hash value and saving it.

In another application, I load the private key and then I'm able to decrypt the information correctly.

The problem is that I want to make quick tests to see if everything's ok.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters.aspx),

> The security of RSA derives from the fact that, given the public key { e, n }, it is computationally infeasible to calculate d, either directly or by factoring n into p and q. Therefore, any part of the key related to d, p, or q must be kept secret.

so the most important parameters of the private key are the exponent and the primes (D, P, Q).

My test was to modify the private key before loading it. First, I changed one character in the first prime and I got a bad key. Same when just modifying one character in the second prime.

But when I modified one character in the exponent, it was still able to correctly decode it. So my question is, which things can be changed from the private key and still be able to decode, and which are essential?

Comment: When you change the private exponent, even by one bit, it should not be able to decrypt. The private exponent is used in the decryption process: m = c ^ d (mod n) where c is the cipher, d is the private exponent, and n is the modulus. (m is the decrypted data)

Comment: d, is the most important part of the decryption, you can have a private key consisting of n (the modulus, p x q) and d (private exponent) only. You don't have to know p and q to be able to decrypt, it is just that knowing these will speed up the decryption process significantly

Comment: May be, if p and q are present, the decryption algorithm not uses the d from the key, but re-calculates it.. That's the only logical explanation I can think of.

Comment: Please shows us actual values that you used to make this experiment, as well as the code you tested it with. That is how stackoverflow works.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I'm just using RSACryptoServiceProvider Encrypt, Decrypt, ToXMLString and FromXMLString and manually modifying the saved private key. Do you think some quick pseudocode could help?

Comment: Why can't you show [real code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

While Modulus, Exponent, and D are all that are required to do RSA technically, very few implementations actually use D, because it's much more efficient to do [RSA via the Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm).

While the Windows CAPI (used by RSACryptoServiceProvider) will roundtrip any value of D you import, it doesn't actually use it. Windows CNG (used by RSACng) requires that D be provided on import of a private key, then promptly throws it away, recomputing it on export (or import, I suppose).

You can see that last quirk by generating an RSA key with OpenSSL (which generates `d` via `phi` (which is the form Wikipedia mentions) and importing it into CNG, which when exporting has replaced `d` with the calculation based on `lambda` (LCM(p-1, q-1)).

Anyways, what all this amounts to is that while "changing D is bad" it can, in practice, just be ignored by the library doing the actual math; and that seems to be the case here.  But you shouldn't do it, because it might not interoperate well after going via a PFX or other private key transfer mechanism.